# Change ListView image with checkbox

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I have a problem.
I need to change image in listView item depending on checkbox checked/unchecked.
If checkbox is checked I put one image if false another.

//code

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
String text = "default text";

int[] imgInt = new int[]{
        R.drawable.navigation_accept,
        R.drawable.ic_launcher
};

CheckBox chBox;
ImageView imageView;
 ListView listView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    chBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.list_item_checkbox);

    List<HashMap<String,String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

    for(int i=0;i<1;i++){
        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
        hm.put("text", text);
        hm.put("imgInt", Integer.toString(imgInt[i]) );
        aList.add(hm);
    }

     String[] from = { "text","imgInt"};

     int[] to = { R.id.list_item_text,R.id.list_item_icon};

     SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.item_item, from, to);

     listView = ( ListView ) findViewById(R.id.countryLV);  
     listView.setAdapter(adapter);

     listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
              int position, long id) {


          }
        });
}
```

//code

Comment: post what you have tried so mfar to achieve this and people will help you!!

Comment: you can use onCheckedChanged listener for checkbox.

Comment: its better to implement custom adapter